# Ruby net-ssh-multi: passing a password as a parameter at runtime

Tags: ruby, parameter-passing, net-ssh

I am trying to use net-ssh-multi to run a command on a group of servers.  For this taks, ssh-key authentication is not an option; a password has to be passed to each server defined in the session.use lines.  Here's the problem, 'net/ssh' can take a password parameter, but 'net/ssh/multi' cannot.  What I would like to do is somehting like this:

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/ssh/multi'

#The necessary data is contained in a Ticket object 

my_ticket = Ticket.new

Net::SSH::Multi.start (:password => 'xxxx') do |session|

  # define the servers we want to use

   my_ticket.servers.each do |serv_id|
     session.use "#{my_ticket.user_name}@#{serv_id}"
   end


  # execute commands on all servers
  session.exec "uptime"


  # run the aggregated event loop
  session.loop
end
```

However, this get me:

file.rb:35:in `start': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError) from file.rb:35

I know this is a bit of a n00b question, but I would really appreciate some help.

(http://rubydoc.info/gems/net-ssh-multi/1.1/Net/SSH/Multi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the answer is far simpler than I thought it would be.  Poring over the documentation, I noticed this in the Class: Net::SSH::Multi::Server docs:

> Class: Net::SSH::Multi::Server
>
> Overview:
>
> Encapsulates the connection
> information for a single remote
> server, as  well as the Net::SSH
> session corresponding to that
> information. You'll rarely  need to
> instantiate one of these directly:
> instead,   you should use
> Net::SSH::Multi::Session#use.'

So, no class extending or calls to super-classes are necessary.  The above can be accomplished with:

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/ssh/multi'


#The necessary data is contained in a Ticket object 
my_ticket = Ticket.new


Net::SSH::Multi.start do |session|


  # define the servers we want to use
  my_ticket.servers.each do |session_server|
    session.use session_server , :user =>  my_ticket.user_name ,  \
    :password => my_ticket.user_pass
  end


  # execute commands on all servers
  session.exec my_ticket.command_to_do
 
  # run the aggregated event loop
  session.loop
end
```

Comment: Thanks, @AbeVoelker . I hope that was the _least_ embarrassing thing about my code.

Comment: Hah sorry, wasn't trying to be fickle there. I'm not competent enough in Ruby yet to comment on the validity of it. But it certainly looks *a lot* cleaner than the Expect/Tcl scripts I had to use at my previous job to work around us being unable to use SSH keys (couldn't use Ruby or Perl either). :-)

Comment: @AbeVoelker No worries, I would blush if I were caught "peaking" instead of "piquing"