# Using the ruby gem net-ssh-multi to execute a sudo command on multiple servers at once

Tags: ruby, sudo, net-ssh

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155372/ruby-net-ssh-multi-passing-a-password-as-a-parameter-at-runtime)  I figured out how to start a password-authenticated ssh sessions on multiple servers to run a single command.  Now I need to be able to execute a "sudo" command.  The problem is, that net-ssh-multi does not allocate a pseudo terminal (pty), which sudo needs to run, resulting in the following error:

> [127.0.0.1 : stderr] sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

According to the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/net-ssh-multi/1.1/Net/SSH/Multi/Channel:request_pty), a pseudo-terminal can be allocated with a method call to a channel object, however, the following code does not work:  it generates the "no tty" error above:

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/ssh/multi'

Net::SSH::Multi.start do |session|


  # define the servers we want to use
  my_ticket.servers.each do |session_server|
    session.use session_server , :user =>  user_name ,  \
                              :password => user_pass
  end


 # execute commands on all servers
  session.exec 'sudo ls /root' do |channel, stream, data|
   if data =~ /^\[sudo\] password for user:/
     channel.request_pty # <- problem must be here.
     channel.send_data user_pass
   end

  end

 # run the aggregated event loop
 session.loop
end
```

$ ruby --version

ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i386-cygwin]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try something like this:

```
  channel.request_pty do |c, success|
    if success
      command = "sudo YOUR_COMMAND"
      c.exec(command) do |c, success|
        # Some processing
      end
    end
  end
```

In this case 'sudo' is inside.

Answer (score 3):

You need to request a pty before running the command.

```
session.open_channel do |ch|
  ch.request_pty
  ch.exec "sudo ls /root"
end
```

Also you may remove the tty requeriment from /etc/sudoers. To do it run `visudo` and comment `Defaults requiretty`

Comment: Oh, only if I could do anything to the sudoers file, or even use things like keys for authentication, my life would be so much easier!  But I have the benefit of no less than two separate, huge corporate bureaucracies standing behind me, and, frankly, it would be easier to re-write the ssh protocol than to get approval to change one thing on those servers.  But thanks for the tip.

Comment: this is inside:                                           `Net::SSH.start('HOST', 'USER', :keys=>["~/.ssh/my_ssh_key"]) do |session| ... end`                                                               right?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I wound up doing, thanks to @Christian and this [wonderful Pastie](http://pastie.org/386041):

```
Net::SSH::Multi.start do |session|

# define the servers we want to use
my_ticket.servers.each do |session_server|
  session.use session_server , :user =>  my_ticket.user_name ,  \
  :password => my_ticket.user_pass
end



session.open_channel do |channel|
channel.request_pty do |c, success|
  raise "could not request pty" unless success
  channel.exec   "sudo YOUR_COMMAND"
  channel.on_data do |c_, data|
  if data = /\[sudo\]/
  channel.send_data(@password + "\n")
  end  
   puts data

    end
   end
  end

# run the aggregated event loop
  session.loop
end
```